# Session and View state into asp labels

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, viewstate

I have been struggling with getting view state to work in a simple web site. I am just beginning to learn ASP and I have confused myself trying to research ways to implement view states and session. I want to be able to enter text into a text box and change the view state and session. I have successfully got the session to change and print on a page load, but I cant figure out how to print the view state. I am just confusing myself further by trying to look at other examples and I could use some help with making my viewstates and sessions work.

Here is my .cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Public_Unit3Assignment : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Top of page
    Response.Write("Session State: ");    //Shows what the current session data is
    Response.Write(Session["New"]);

    Response.Write("<br />");

    Response.Write("Veiwstate: ");          //Trying to show what current Viewstate `data is`
    Response.Write(ViewState["NameOfUser"]);



    Response.Write("<br />");

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string str = "Sample ViewState";
        if (ViewState["NameOfUser"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["NameOfUser"] = str;
        }

    }
}

//onlcick to display Viewstate
protected void SubmitForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label2.Text = ViewState["NameOfUser"].ToString();
    ViewState["NameOfUser"] = TextBox1.Text;   //Try to fill viewstate with text from textbox1
    lbl1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
}

//Onlcick event to display session
protected void SubmitForm_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["New"] = SessionTextBox.Text;
    Sessionexample.Text = Session["New"].ToString();  //Trying to enter session data into label 
    Sessionexample.Text = SessionTextBox.Text;        //Trying to enter session data into label 
    SessionResult.Text = SessionTextBox.Text;         //Trying to enter session data into label 

}
```

Here is my .aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Assignment.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Unit3Assignment.aspx.cs" Inherits="Public_Unit3Assignment" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContentPlaceholder" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyContentPlaceholder" Runat="Server">

    <div class="Content">


        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />


        <br /><br />


        <asp:UpdatePanel
            id="up1"
            runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <br />


                <br />

            <asp:Label
                id="lbl1"
                text="ViewState Example"
                runat="server"></asp:Label>

                <br />

                <asp:TextBox
                    id="TextBox1"
                    Text="ViewState Example TextBox"
                    runat="Server" />

                <br />

            <asp:Label
                id="Label2"
                text="ViewState Result"
                runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <br />

                <asp:TextBox
                    id="TextBox2"
                    Text="ViewState Result TextBox"
                    ReadOnly="true"
                    runat="Server" />

                <br />

                <asp:Button
                    runat="server"
                    onclick="SubmitForm_Click"
                    text="Submit & set name" />

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>





        </div>

    <asp:UpdatePanel
        id="up2"
        runat="server">

       <ContentTemplate>

           <asp:Label
               id="Sessionexample"
               text="Session Example"
               runat="server" />

           <br />
           <asp:TextBox
               id="SessionTextBox"
               text="SessionTextBox"
               runat="server" />
           <br />

           <asp:Label
               id="SessionResult"
               text="Session Result"
               runat="server" />
           <br />
           <asp:TextBox
               id="SessionResultTextBox"
               text="SessionResultTextBox"
               readonly="true"
               runat="server" />

           <br />
        <asp:Button
            id="btn2"
            runat="server"
            onclick="SubmitForm_Click2"
            text="Submit for Session"/>

           <br />
       </ContentTemplate>


    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: viewstate, is not to be messed with, asp.net uses it to store control state, sesssion state is used to determine if the current session is valid, think you may be confusing that with session variables or query string, both of these you can use to hold data with session it always going to be temp.

Comment: You should avoid using `Response.Write` in a page context, as it's going to write the results to the end (or beginning, can't remember which) of the file. Instead, append the text to a place holder or some other control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing as I don't think I was specific enough in my question, but I answered my own question by looking through examples on microsoft.com.. It was hard to explain what I was trying to do here with Session and View state, but essentially I needed to place the session data into a text box from the input of and onclick event. My problems derived from not knowing about how to use: if (IsPostBack). I am still new to ASP and C#. Thanks for the response too, I did need to do some reading on the subject. Anyway here is the code I was looking to create:
.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //session set
        Session["message"] = "Hello World";
        //session get
        lblMessage.Text = Session["message"].ToString();

        //viewstate set
        ViewState["message"] = "Hi there world";
        //viewstate get
        lblMessageView.Text = ViewState["message"].ToString();


    }

    protected void SubmitForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            ViewState["New"] = TextView1.Text;         //makes new viewstate with text result
            TextView2.Text = ViewState["New"].ToString(); //Trying to enter viewstate data in text box
        }

    }

    protected void SubmitForm_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["New"] = SessionTextBox.Text; //makes new session with text result
            SessionResultTextBox.Text = Session["New"].ToString();  //Trying to enter session data into text box
        }

    }



}
```

.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Assignment.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Unit3Assignment.aspx.cs" Inherits="Public_Unit3Assignment" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContentPlaceholder" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyContentPlaceholder" Runat="Server">



    <asp:Label
        id="session"
        runat="server"
        text="Session Message: " />

<asp:Label
    id="lblMessage"
    runat="server" 
    backcolor="Yellow"
    forecolor="Black" />

    <br />

    <asp:Label
        id="viewstate"
        runat="server"
        text="ViewState Message: " />

<asp:Label
    id="lblMessageView"
    runat="server" 
    backcolor="red"
    forecolor="green" />

<br /><br /><br />

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel
        id="up1"
        runat="server" >

    <ContentTemplate>
        <br />

    <asp:Label
        id="View1"
        text="ViewState Example"
        runat="server" />

        <br />

        <asp:TextBox
            id="TextView1"
            text="ViewStateTextBox"
            runat="server" />

        <br />

       <asp:Label
        id="View2"
        text="ViewState Result"
        runat="server" />

        <br />

         <asp:TextBox
            id="TextView2"
            text="ViewStateResultTextBox"
            runat="server" />

        <br />

        <asp:Button
            id="btn1"
            runat="server"
            onclick="SubmitForm_Click" 
            text="Show ViewState"/>

        </ContentTemplate>

        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <br /><br /><br />

        <asp:UpdatePanel
        id="up2"
        runat="server">

       <ContentTemplate>

           <asp:Label
               id="Sessionexample"
               text="Session Example"
               runat="server" />

           <br />
           <asp:TextBox
               id="SessionTextBox"
               text="SessionTextBox"
               runat="server" />
           <br />

           <asp:Label
               id="SessionResult"
               text="Session Result"
               runat="server" />
           <br />
           <asp:TextBox
               id="SessionResultTextBox"
               text="SessionResultTextBox"
               readonly="true"
               runat="server" />

           <br />
        <asp:Button
            id="btn2"
            runat="server"
            onclick="SubmitForm_Click2"
            text="Submit for Session"/>

           <br />
       </ContentTemplate>


    </asp:UpdatePanel>



</asp:Content>
```